# Main Class not found error migrating from maven to gradle

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, gradle, spring-cloud-netflix

I am migrating a maven project to gradle in STS.

My pom.xml is :

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myPack</groupId>
    <artifactId>sdk-devproxy</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-RELEASE</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>sdk-devproxy</name>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>Edgware.SR3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.auth0/java-jwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>sdk-devproxy</finalName>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.myPack.devproxy.DevProxyApp</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have used automatic maven to gradle conversion command "gardle init" and I got the below build.gradle.

```
    apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'com.myPack'
version = '0.0.1-RELEASE'

description = """sdk-devproxy"""

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8



repositories {

     maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
}
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-oauth2', version:'1.2.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-zuul', version:'1.4.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version:'1.5.10.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-log4j', version:'1.3.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'com.auth0', name: 'java-jwt', version:'3.3.0'
}
```

For this build is successful but while I run as spring boot app its giving

```
    Error: Could not find or load main class com.myPack.mindsphere.devproxy.DevProxyApp
```

I have tried refreshing,rebuilding, update gradle project etc.. i have also specified main class name  like below :

```
    jar {
  manifest {
    attributes(
      'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
      'Main-Class': 'com.myPack.mindsphere.devproxy.DevProxyApp'
    )
  }
}
```

What might be the issue:

- plugin or packaging issue?
- jar compatibility issue ?
- or something else ?

Comment: try with removing Class Path for a while i.e. `attributes   'Main-Class': 'com.myPack.mindsphere.devproxy.DevProxyApp'` and share what error you get.

Comment: same error without that

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using:

- `./gradlew bootRepackage` or `./gradlew bootJar` to generate the executable jar
- `./gradlew bootRun` to run

described as per

> https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/

If you are on gradle version **Gradle 3.4** or later which uses bootJar task in place of bootRepackage as per latest documentation https://spring.io/blog/2017/04/05/spring-boot-s-new-gradle-plugin

> The bootRepackage task has been replaced with bootJar and bootWar
>   tasks for building executable jars and wars respectively. Both tasks
>   extend their equivalent standard Gradle jar or war task, giving you
>   access to all of the usual configuration options and behaviour.

The running configuration for your app:

1. Update your build file with below:

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
//apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.myPack'
version = '0.0.1-RELEASE'

description = """sdk-devproxy"""

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(
          "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

repositories {

     maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
}
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-oauth2', version:'1.2.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-zuul', version:'1.4.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version:'1.5.10.RELEASE'
    //compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-log4j', version:'1.3.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'com.auth0', name: 'java-jwt', version:'3.3.0'
}

bootJar {
    mainClassName = 'com.myPack.mindsphere.devproy.DevProxyApp'
}
```

2. Build the jar using below. This will generate sdk-devproxy-0.0.1-RELEASE.jar in build/libs directory of your project.

   **gradle build**
3. Run the application using:

   **gradlew bootRun**

Comment: @smrutiranjan: Please find a running configuration for your program and the way you can run it as a boot app.